# Quantum Coherence in a Two-level System in the Density Matrix Formalism

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density-operator, decoherence, laser-interaction, two-level-system

Dealing with semiclassical light-matter interaction, in particular the interaction between an electromagnetic field and a two level system using the density matrix formalism, I learned that the system can be described by the following Liouville equation:
$$ i\hbar \frac{\partial ρ}{\partial t} = [H, ρ] $$
where $ρ$ is the density matrix and $H$ is the Hamiltonian of the system. In this case, assuming $H_0$ to be the unperturbed Hamiltonian of the two level system, $H'$ to be the Hamiltonian describing the interaction with the electromagnetic field (e. g. in the electric dipole moment approximation) and $H_r$ to be a randomizing Hamiltonian describing the interaction of the system with the environment, we can write:
$$ H = H_0 + H' + H_r $$
and study independently the three commutators between these Hamiltonians and the Density matrix operator. In particular, considering the randomizing Hamiltonian, a possible phenomenological approach would be to write:
$$ [H_r, ρ]_{jk} = -i\hbar \frac{ρ_{jk} - ρ_{jk}^0}{τ_{jk}} $$
for the $jk$-th matrix element, where $ρ_{jk}^0$ is the value of that matrix element at equilibrium, when it is unperturbed. Solving this equation, as it is also pointed out in the answer to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386092/119161) question, I know that I would obtain the temporal evolution of the diagonal terms, that gives the probability of finding the system in a certain eigenstate if the unperturbed Hamiltonian for a given mixed state and that will relax toward their equilibrium value in a typical time called population decay (or longitudinal decay) time, and of the off-diagonal terms. The off-diagonal terms give the probability of "finding" the system in a coherent superposition of two eigenstates of the unperturbed Hamiltonian, they will oscillate at a frequency proportional to the energy difference between these eigenstates and they will fast relax toward zero with a typical time called dephasing time (or transverse relaxation time).

Here comes my question: **why quantum coherence can only be lost? Why does the interaction with the environment only lead to a loss of coherence, not actually bringing an incoherent state into a coherent one?** Is there a theoretical reason, apart from experimental evidence, for this? Does this reduce to the argument, already present in classical statistical physics, that (stated in a brutal way) says that "it is not impossible, it is only extremely improbable"?

Comment: You might find this interesting: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409753/

Comment: @DanielSank Thank you for your comment, however it is a little bit too advanced for my present knowledge of the topic, unfortunately!